# define() won't display special characters - charset utf-8

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

Website doesn't display special characters if they come from a define() function **of a file in a different directory level than the one file displaying it (this part is edited/added)**.

Example:

```
<?php
echo "codificação"; // displays "codificação"
```

WHILE

```
define( 'codification' , 'codificação');
echo codification; // displays "codifica��o"
```

**PHP 5.6**

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

**HEADERS**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Why does it happen and what may be the solution for this?

Website: [bioprecisa.com.br](http://bioprecisa.com.br)

Comment: Are you sure that both files are UTF-8 encoded? When I do the test with your data and definitions, everything is ok. Test1: define in the same file that echoes the HTML code. Test2: define in a separate include file. When my script is ANSI encoded it looks like you describe.

Comment: I just had a look at the web page you linked. To me it also looks like the page / creating script where not UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @hherger, how do I determine if it is ANSI encoded?

Comment: Use sn editor like Notepad++ on Windows. There youca

Comment: With an editor like Noteoad++ (Windows) you can see and change the encoding.

Comment: @hherger, talking to my hosting provider I found that when they open my files they see the black diamond inside of them (not only in the browser). They are doing further checks. On Notepad++ I see under the "Format" menu, a few encoding options. Is that what you are telling me?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm taking about. With Notepad++ you could try "Enoding" | "Convert to..." (in German "Kodierung" | "Kovertiere zu..."). Maybe you have to change the black diamonds once in every page. Anyway, I'm quite sure tthat these characters indicate a character encoding problem.

Comment: Oh, I just saw that the website (bioprecisa.com.br) now looks better.

Comment: @hherger, yes, it looks better, but if you check what encoding it's using, you will see it is "ISO-8859-1", not "UTF-8". With UTF-8 it will just mess everything again...

Comment: Sure. The default content type is UTF-8, the "meta" charset is defined as UTF-8, and probably the web server adds a corresponding header. So, the encoding character set that matches these definitions should be "UTF-8" (without BOM) too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101504/discussion-between-rafael-vidal-and-hherger).

Comment: "ISO-8859-1", or "latin 1" would cover the Portuguese characters. But, to be ready for any character set, e.g. asian characters, I'd recommend UTF-8. And I am quite sure you only had to convert the files once (Notepad++) and store them in UTF-8 for that.